# Cannot access XDocument with IEnumerable Loop C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, ienumerable

I am trying to load some data from an XML document using `System.Xml.Linq`, but when I try to use an IEnumerable object and a `from item in doc` statement I get the following Error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'XDocument'. 'Select' not found.

Here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

    public class DataManager
    {
        // GET: Data
        private void LoadTestData()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> users;
            XDocument testData = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\gross\source\repos\Database Sandbox\Database Sandbox\App_Data\TestData.xml");

            users = from user in testData;
        }
    }
```

I looked around but every solution I saw was just *"remember to have the using System.Linq statement"*

The project is set up in Visual Studio 2017 with ASP.NET + MVC 5

Comment: `XDocument` is not an `IEnumerable`. What r u trying to get from xml? How xml looks like?

Comment: users = (from user in testData \r\n select user).ToList(); maybe like this?

Comment: Should be : List<XElement> users = testData.Descendant("user").ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XDocument does not implement IEnumerable. It exposes several methods to access the structure of the document that return IEnumerables of things like XElement or XAttribute.

An example would be testData.Elements() or testData.Descendents()

It's these that will expose collections that you can use Linq with

Comment: This was it. Now I just need to mess around with exactly how I need to format the call to pull the data I want.

Comment: @user3776749 take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-an-xdocument-vs-querying-an-xelement and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.7.1